# Why my ram specs shows different manufacturer?

Tags: memory, 64-bit

So I bought these so-called "Kingston" SODIMM rams but when I hit  `wmic memorychip list full`  it says that the manufacturer code is 802C. That code is for "Micron Technology, Inc.". Is this normal or did the seller just deceive me?

```
BankLabel=BANK 0
Capacity=4294967296
DataWidth=64
Description=Physical Memory
DeviceLocator=DIMM0
FormFactor=12
HotSwappable=
InstallDate=
InterleaveDataDepth=1
InterleavePosition=1
Manufacturer=802C
MemoryType=0
Model=
Name=Physical Memory
OtherIdentifyingInfo=
PartNumber=16JSF51264HZ-1G4D1
PositionInRow=
PoweredOn=
Removable=
Replaceable=
SerialNumber=32418F63
SKU=
Speed=1067
Status=
Tag=Physical Memory 0
TotalWidth=64
TypeDetail=128
Version=

BankLabel=BANK 2
Capacity=4294967296
DataWidth=64
Description=Physical Memory
DeviceLocator=DIMM2
FormFactor=12
HotSwappable=
InstallDate=
InterleaveDataDepth=1
InterleavePosition=2
Manufacturer=802C
MemoryType=0
Model=
Name=Physical Memory
OtherIdentifyingInfo=
PartNumber=16JSF51264HZ-1G4D1
PositionInRow=
PoweredOn=
Removable=
Replaceable=
SerialNumber=FB4DA8AB
SKU=
Speed=1067
Status=
Tag=Physical Memory 1
TotalWidth=64
TypeDetail=128
Version=
```

Comment: There are only like 4 actual manufactures of DDR memory. What you purchased was manufactured by Micron and branded as Kingston. I don’t believe Kingston is actually one of those manufacturers by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, so this is ok

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be “ok” the parts work at their advertised specifications I assume? The only thing I will point out is that the part number is directly linked to Micron not Kingston. I assume you purchased from a reliable retailer that doesn’t ship from China?

Comment: There are only 3 RAM manufacturers, Micron, Hynix & Samsung. Everybody else is a re-brand of those [Crucial is exclusively Micron, idk who the other major resellers belong to]. Kingston is, of course, a reseller, but that doesn't make them in any way untrustworthy. They're one of the majors.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for informing me about the part number. I bought them from some retailer on an e-commerce platform. Generally, I don't trust them in the place I live. DDR3, 1066 MHz, 4 GB... everything's cool but still, the brand is different that's why I asked. Also, the stickers on the packaging seem suspicious. Anyways thanks again.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the real manufacturer of your RAM by looking at the line:

```
PartNumber=16JSF51264HZ-1G4D1
```

If you then search for this Part Number, you will find many references.

For example:

- [PassMark Micron Technology 16JSF51264HZ-1G4D1 4GB](https://www.memorybenchmark.net/ram.php?ram=Micron+Technology+16JSF51264HZ-1G4D1+4GB&id=587)
- Amazon:
  [Micron 4GB PC3-10600 DDR3-1333MHz Non-ECC Memory Module MT16JSF51264HZ-1G4D1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DIWPBRO)

It is a Micron chip rebranded and sold by Kingston.